# virtual host on Apache in windows7

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, virtualhost

As i tried to configure my virtual host on `apache(xampp) in windows7` - x64.

I put something like this,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/mysite/public"
   ServerName www.mysite.com 
   ErrorLog "logs/www.mysite.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/www.mysite.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) i put something like this,

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mysite.com
```

And i run it on the browser,

`http://www.mysite.com` -

Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at `www.mysite.com`.

Do i missed something to configure? Any ideas..

Comment: `mysite.com` is not the same as `www.mysite.com`. Did you add the latter as well to your hosts file?

Comment: And have you restarted the web-server?

Comment: @jeroen : i just stoped apache from xampp control panel and then started it

Comment: @jeroen : should i change '127.0.0.1  mysite.com' to '127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com'?

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts file needs to be

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       mysite.com
    127.0.0.1       www.mysite.com
```

Because mysite.com and www.mysite.com are not the same. I recommend add ServerAlias into your vhost.conf and change ServerName

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/mysite/public"
       ServerName mysite.com
       ServerAlias www.mysite.com 
       ErrorLog "logs/www.mysite.com-error.log"
       CustomLog "logs/www.mysite.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i stoped apache from xampp control panel and then started it. error : Server not found

Comment: when i write localhost in my url , it goes to the projects/mysite/public.and when i write mysite.com in my url , it doesn't go to the projects/mysite/public. why?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/mysite/public" #Make sure that your httpd.conf file has DocumentRoot set to your htdocs folder or the folder in which your site is in.
    CustomLog logs/site.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog logs/site.com.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: when i write `localhost` in my url , it goes to the `projects/mysite/public`. why?

Comment: when i write `mysite.com` in my url , it doesn't go to the `projects/mysite/public`. why?!

Comment: Because in your virtual host file projects/mysite/public directory is the first site. if you move your some other site to top then localhost will open it.
Always use the server alias or server name you defined in virtual host file to get the site you want. But if you type localhost it doesn't matter but it will always redirect you the the first site defined in virtual host file.

Comment: i add <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
</VirtualHost> to the httpd-vhosts.conf , now i can access localhost